# Get backspace into C char*

Tags: c, string, unix, char

I want to return a null-terminated char* that contains a backspace character *without `malloc`'ing it*.
Specifically, I want the string to be {backspace-character, space-character, backspace-character, null-character} and nothing else.

For a "regular" string, I know I could say

```
char* s = "regular";
return s;
```

Then `s` is safe to pass around to other functions because it points to the string `regular`, which is a global declared outside of the stack. However, the only way I can think of accomplishing this with backspace would be

```
char* s = {0x08, ' ', 0x08, '\0'};
return s;
```

but this seems problematic because now the array I declared is on the stack, and will not be valid for use in the calling function. Again, I don't want to `malloc` this string because I don't want to deal with having to `free` it later. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include a backspace in a string literal as `\b` e.g. `"\b \b"`

Answer (score 1):

```
char*   s = "\b \b";
```

is this what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using a string constant per the other answers, you can do

```
static char s[] = {0x08, ' ', '0x08, '\0'};
return s;
```